# My function always returns false the first time

Tags: swift, function, nsurlsession

This may be a bit of an obscure question, but I cannot seem to figure out what is happening here.  I have a "login" function that checks a username and password against an API.  For some reason, calling this function returns **false** the first time, but if  I call the function a second time, it returns the proper true, assuming I enter the correct credentials.

Here is the function:

```
if testLogin(usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("dismissLogin", sender: self)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Login Problem"
            alert.message = "Wrong username or password."
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")
            alert.show()
        }
    }
```

The **testLogin** function appears here;

```
func testLogin(username: String, password: String) -> Bool {

    let jsonString = "{\"username\":\"\(username)\",\"password\":\"\(password)\"}"
    let myURL = "http://myurl.com/api/login.php"

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: myURL)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

    request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
        let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        do {
            let json:AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

            if let result = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
                if let status = result["Status"] as! Int? {
                    if status == 200 {
                        self.loginCheck = true
                    } else {
                        self.loginCheck = false
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }            
    }   
    task.resume()
    return loginCheck
}
```

Sorry for the length.  I can't seem to fathom, though, why calling testLogin the first time returns **false**, but calling it the second time returns true.  Almost as if the function is not calling the website fast enough and is returning false, but the second time I call the function, it has had time to check the website?

Comment: Another variation of the "*dataTaskWithRequest is **asynchronous** ..."* theme ...

Comment: Thanks @MartinR.  This inevitably was a duplicate of the **dataTaskWithRequest is asynchronous** theme, I just didn't realize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `testLogin` is incorrect. Method `dataTaskWithRequest` is asynchronous. You need to create two callbacks `success` and `failure` (closures). Which will be called if request completes. Look at this https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had actually tried implementing a closure originally, but didn't seem to get the same result.  I took some time to further research and it is working properly now; thank you!  I'm purposely avoiding using any third-party libraries (like Alamofire), just to learn the basis of how things work on my own.  I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: No problems. "I'm purposely avoiding using any third-party libraries (like Alamofire)". You can just look at implementation and will do conclusions.